# How to align shapes and text accurately in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to align object such that they resze according to the unused space?

Here is an example - there are three objects, a background square and foreground text with a highlight rectangle below the text. The text and the highlight should be spaced as though there is an equal amount of space either side (or near enough)...

[image]

This is as far as I have got (I have tried a variety of different iterations although the Spacer command seems a little ideosynchratic (depending on a variety of factors I don't entirely understand yet)...

```
struct hlGroup: View {
    var body : some View {
        Color(red:20/255,green: 45/255, blue:71/255)
            .frame(width:50, height:56)
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .overlay(alignment:.center){
                Spacer()
                VStack(){
            Text(String(0))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(Font.system(size:30, weight:.bold))
            HStack(spacing: 2){
                hlShow(hlColor: Color(red:100/255, green: 227/255, blue: 50/255))
            }
            Spacer()
}}}}

struct hlShow: View {
    let hlColor :Color
    var body: some View {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(hlColor)
                .frame(width:30, height:6)
                .cornerRadius(2)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing some specific requirement, the layout could be easily achieved using a `VStack` as the main container (added a border to text acting as a bounds indicator - previewing at 80 × 80):

```
struct SODemo: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Text")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(Font.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                .border(.red)
            Spacer()
            Color.green.frame(height: 6)
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(6)
    }
}
```

[image]